# Disable ASP.NET redirection to another IIS Virtual Directory

Tags: asp.net, iis, configuration, iis-7, web-config

Let's suppose I have multiple ASP.NET sites deployed to IIS in multiple virtual directories, like this -

```
/Site1 
/Site2 
/Site3 
etc...
```

Users can currently make a request on Site1 like this: '/Site1/../Site2' to access pages on Site2.

Is there a way to configure Site1 so such redirects are not allowed?

Ideally this would be configured in Web.Config, but I'm ok with making config changes in IIS if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't they just request '/Site2'? Preventing the redirect is pointless if they can just go to '/Site2' directly, no?

Comment: That;s the thing: we are using a proxy (Mule) that allows requests to /Site1, but not /Site2.  By using the 'Site1/../Site2' trick, it's not a redirect, but IIS and ASP.NET allow by default the code on /Site2 to execute.

Comment: In 'Site1', I was thinking of looking at the request url and throwing an exception if I see "../" in the url - but I was wondering if there was something a bit more elegant using the Web.Config, IIS, or routing.

Comment: By any chance do you have parent paths enabled? See here: https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/kb/a1115/how-to-enable-parent-paths-in-iis7-dedicated-vps.aspx

Comment: Yes, we do have Parent Paths enabled, but we use them for referencing relative images and other features that may break if I disable them (for relative image examples see: http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/benefits-and-pitfalls-disabling-parent-paths)

Comment: Well it sounds like you need to disable parent paths and change your image references to absolute paths instead of relative paths. It's better practice to do that anyway.